# Unable to push git changes to remote

Tags: git

I can push my changes last time. However, there was a problem in something, I think merge stuff.

So, to solve my problem, I create another local directory, and get the recent changes. The problem now is that when I made changes, I can't push it to remote. How to solve?

Comment: wow, you're missing a whole lot of needed detail. How about telling us what message or error did you get? and what you've tried in order to address your issue.

Comment: Pushing to git@bitbucket.org:sample.git
To bitbucket.org:sample.git
 ! [rejected]          same-name-branch -> same-name-branch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@sample.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: What is the error message? What were your commands?

Answer (score 0):

```
[rejected] same-name-branch -> same-name-branch (non-fast-forward)
```

The simple way would be to accept the hint given, and do a git pull first.
If you want to replay you commit on top of the fetched commits (instead of merging), you can do:

```
git pull --rebase
```

In both cases, you will be able to push afterward.